# How did we get lower and upper bounds in triple integral

Tags: calculus

I cannot understand how we arrived to these bounds... the article says z equals to two expressions and then somehow we get bounds where z is in between them. I do not understand why plane is upper bound and paraboloid is lower bound... (link to article https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/modal/a/triple-integrals)

Consider the region R bounded by the following two surfaces:

The paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$

The plane $z = 2(x + y + 1)$

[image]

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi sure, sorry for delay :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out the region is a good start try to plot it in the planes $z-x$ or $z-y$. In this way you can easily convince yourself that there is a region where the plane is upper bound and paraboloid is lower bound.

[image]

To find this region region in the plane x-y you can equate the equation of the paraboloid and of the plane and find that it is a circle, indeed

$$x^2+y^2=2(x+y+1)\implies (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=4$$

Note that from the inequality

$$2(x+y+1)>x^2+y^2\implies (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2<4$$

we can directly deduce that the region where the plane is upper bound and paraboloid is lower bound corresponds to the interior of the circle.

[image]

Comment: is there any way to get lower and upper bounds without plotting? Like how do I figure it out without plotting?

Comment: Yes you can do it directly from the equations, I’ll add this way to the answer.

Comment: I am still a bit unclear how we deduced that paraboloid is lower bound from the inequality that we obtained... Sorry I am lame in math. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: the fact that we got circle from the first graph is also confusing (by equating the two equations and getting a circle out of it).. I am not sure what it means.

Comment: @YohanRoth The circle equation is directly obtained from the given equations.

Comment: thats a understand. I cannot quite get the reasoning... how we realized what equation is lower and upper bounds. Like I cannot derive reasoning, but surely I see how algebra works out